# Query to list "last backup time" listing wrong times ( SQL Server 2008 R2 )

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I use this query to list last backup dates of our databases:

```
SELECT SDB.NAME AS DATABASENAME,
COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), MAX(BUS.BACKUP_FINISH_DATE), 101),'-') AS LASTBACKUPTIME
FROM SYS.SYSDATABASES SDB
LEFT OUTER JOIN MSDB.DBO.BACKUPSET BUS ON BUS.DATABASE_NAME=SDB.NAME
GROUP BY SDB.NAME
    ORDER BY 2 ASC
```

But today, it shows me "09/15/2015" for all databases, but we had a problem in the cluster, so the backup job didn't run. Why is this query listing "09/15/2015' if there are no backups for today?

[image]

last time the job run was 09/14/2015.

---

Edit 1:

With James Anderson's query, I got this too ( filtering with `bckset.[type] ='D`)

Again, I don't have backups from 2015-09-15, only 2015-09-14.

---

EDIT 2:

With some tests, I see that these queries shows me last backup date, even if I only have log backups. Is there a way to list "last full backup" date??

[image]

Comment: Any chance the msdb was restored from other server ? Can you check that just to rule that out ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem may be that the backup set was created but the backup did not complete. I use the query below to check my backups

```
USE MSDB;
GO

SELECT TOP  300
            bckset.database_name AS DatabaseName,
            bckmdiaset.physical_device_name AS BackupLocation,
            CASE 
                WHEN bckset.backup_size <= '10485760' THEN
                    CAST(CAST(bckset.backup_size/1024 AS INT) AS VARCHAR(14)) + ' ' + 'KB'
                ELSE
                    CASE 
                        WHEN bckset.backup_size <= '1048576000' THEN
                            CAST(CAST(bckset.backup_size/1024/1024 AS INT) AS VARCHAR(14)) + ' ' + 'MB'
                        ELSE
                            CAST(CAST(bckset.backup_size/1024/1024/1024 AS INT) AS VARCHAR(14)) + ' ' + 'GB'
                    END
            END backupSize,
            CAST (bckset.backup_start_date AS smalldatetime) AS StartTime,
            CAST (bckset.backup_finish_date AS smalldatetime)FinishTime,
            CASE 
                WHEN CAST(DATEDIFF(second, bckset.backup_start_date, bckset.backup_finish_date )AS VARCHAR (4)) <= 60 THEN
                    CAST(DATEDIFF(second, bckset.backup_start_date,bckset.backup_finish_date) AS VARCHAR(4))+ ' ' + 'Seconds'
                ELSE
                    CAST(DATEDIFF(minute, bckset.backup_start_date,bckset.backup_finish_date) AS VARCHAR(4))+ ' ' + 'Minutes'
            END AS TimeTaken,
            CAST(bckset.first_lsn AS VARCHAR(25)) AS FirstLogSequenceNumber,
            CAST(bckset.last_lsn AS VARCHAR(25)) AS LastLogSequenceNumber,
            CASE bckset.[type]
                WHEN 'D' THEN 'Full'
                WHEN 'I' THEN 'Differential database'
                WHEN 'L' THEN 'Transaction Log'
                WHEN 'F' THEN 'File or filegroup'
                WHEN 'G' THEN 'Differential file'
                WHEN 'P' THEN 'Partial'
                WHEN 'Q' THEN 'Differential partial'
            END AS BackupType,
            bckset.server_name As ServerName,
            bckset.recovery_model As RecoveryModel,
            CASE bckset.is_snapshot
                WHEN '0' THEN 'FALSE'
                WHEN '1' THEN 'TRUE'
            END AS IsSnapshot,
            CASE [compatibility_level]
                WHEN 60 THEN 'SQL Server 6.0'
                WHEN 65 THEN 'SQL Server 6.5'
                WHEN 70 THEN 'SQL Server 7.0'
                WHEN 80 THEN 'SQL Server 2000'
                WHEN 90 THEN 'SQL Server 2005'
                WHEN 100 THEN 'SQL Server 2008'
                WHEN 110 THEN 'SQL Server 2012'
                WHEN 120 THEN 'SQL Server 2014'
            END AS CompatibilityLevel

FROM        msdb.dbo.backupset bckset
INNER JOIN  msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily bckmdiaset ON bckset.media_set_id = bckmdiaset.media_set_id

---WHERE bckset.database_name = ''

ORDER BY    backup_start_date DESC, backup_finish_date
```

Comment: How can I list only FULL backups? `where bckset.[type] ='D'` is returning me wrong values.

Comment: That should work. How are the values wrong?

Comment: It says again, that I have backups from 2015-09-15 15:51:00 But I don't have. I will update the picture in my question ok?

Comment: Are you sure someone hasn't manually ran some backups after the incident with the cluster? Can you check the location stated in the 'BackupLocation' column to make sure backps are not there?

Comment: Did you check the locations? The server wouldn't record this information if a backup didn't happen. The backups aren't on the other node in the cluster are they?

Comment: Yes I'm pretty sure. You can see it in that picure of the job. Last time it was succesfull was 09/14/2015  ( with backups from 09/13/2015 ). Looks like it is listing log backups too. Even if theres no full backup, it shows us the log backup being the last one.

Comment: But the location shows my Full backup DIrectory. I have no Idea what's wrong.

Comment: Well i tested the query with an empty environment. It shows me last backup date date even If I only have log backups.

Comment: Is that with the `where bckset.[type] ='D'` ?

Comment: yes...even with queries I found over the internet, I have the same results.